# What does ::Instance() mean?

Tags: c++, objective-c++

```
A& B =
        C::Instance()-> D;
```

I have this line of code that I am suppose to write an algorithm for, but I don't understand what `C::Instance()` means or does. Could someone help me understand this line?

Comment: Do you understand what [factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is?

Comment: @MohitJain I think you mean Singleton.

Comment: @Borgleader Good point. It may be singleton or factory. More chances are singleton.

Answer (score 6):

`Instance` is a static member function of `C`.
It returns a pointer to something that has a member variable `D`, and `D` is of either type `A` or `A&`.
The thing `Instance` returns is probably the only existing instance of `C` itself, making the instance a *singleton*.
(But that's a guess based on the name and the usage.)

Answer (score 0):

[Static member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) `::Instance()` is usually implemented when we need just 1 instance of a class and is implemented in a way that follows singleton implementation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34279694)